# parsing a file name using a batch file

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd, substring

So I'm a volunteer helping out a blind fellow once a week.  For the last 9 years now part of what I do is help him put his audio books on to what's called a 'daisy streamer'.  Basically an audio file player that takes an SD card.

Every week he gets a bunch of CD's mailed to him from the blind institute.  I go through the same process all the time - I check the title of the book, create a matching folder on his SD card (F:/VRDTB), then copy the complete contents of the CD to the folder.

So, for instance, if the book was called 'Harry Potter', I'd do something like this:

- open F: in windows explorer (his SD card)
- switch to F:/VRDTB
- Create the folder Harry Potter
- Copy everything on the CD drive to F:/VRDTB/Harry Potter

This is fine but I'd like to make a batch file so he can do it himself.

The first file on the CD is always either an m3u file or some other file that contains the name, author, and some identifier.  For instance the one in front of me right now looks like this:

```
Emily_Carr_a_biography_Tippett_Ma-DC03026-CNIB-INCA.m3u
```

So I wrote a batch file that finds the first file, replaces the underscores with spaces.  It looks like this

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir e: /b /o-n') do set file=%%F
echo 1st alpha file is %file%

set str=%file%
set str=%str:_= %
echo str with spaces removed is %str%
```

I'm stuck at the next step, though.  I'd like to trim everything right of the first hyphen (including the hyphen) off so that the title would, in this case, end after the 'Ma'  It's not perfect but it would work.  In this case the 'Ma' is the first couple of letters of the author's name - Maria Tippett.

Once I can trim it from there then I can just have the batch file create the folder with the parsed name and xcopy everything from the cd drive to that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=-" %%F...
```

By default, the first *token* is assigned to the *metavariable* `%%F`. The characters between the `=` and `"` for `delims` form a `delimiter set`. Any sequence of any delimiter char from the `delimiter set` delimits the *tokens* on the line.

You could use

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%F...
```

but the `tokens=1` is redundant as `1` is the default. If you were to set `tokens=2` in this instance, then `%%F` would be assigned the second token, ie **DC03026** and `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%F...` would assign **Emily_Carr_a_biography_Tippett_Ma** to `%%F` and **DC03026** to `%%G`